# Regex for SPARQL

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, apache-jena

I have downloaded dbpedia_quotationsbook.zip from [dbpedia](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/1.0/) which contains dbpedia_quotationsbook.nt triplestore.

In this triplestore

> subject is authorname
>        predicate is "sameas"
>   object is authorcode

I have tried this querying triplestore using JENA , simple queries are running.

Now **I want all authorcode whose authorname matches partially with given string** .
So I tried following query

```
select ?code
where
{

FILTER regex(?name, "^Rob")  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> ?code.

}
```

> above query should return all authorcodes whose authorname contains
>   "Rob"

I am getting following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "." ". "" at line 5, column 74.
Was expecting one of:
    <IRIref> ...
    <PNAME_NS> ...
    <PNAME_LN> ...
    <BLANK_NODE_LABEL> ...
    <VAR1> ...
    <VAR2> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    <INTEGER> ...
    <DECIMAL> ...
    <DOUBLE> ...
    <INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ...
    <INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL1> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL2> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL_LONG1> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL_LONG2> ...
    "(" ...
    <NIL> ...
    "[" ...
    <ANON> ...

    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.perform(ParserSPARQL11.java:102)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.parse$(ParserSPARQL11.java:53)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.SPARQLParser.parse(SPARQLParser.java:34)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:148)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:80)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:53)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:41)
    at rdfcreate.NewClass.query(NewClass.java:55)
    at rdfcreate.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:97)
```

Jena Code

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Dataset;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

/**
 *
 * @author swapnil
 */
public class NewClass {
    String read()
        {
               final String tdbDirectory = "C:\\TDBLoadGeoCoordinatesAndLabels"; 


    String dataPath = "F:\\Swapnil Drive\\Project Stuff\\Project data 2015 16\\Freelancer\\SPARQL\\dbpedia_quotationsbook.nt";


     Model tdbModel = TDBFactory.createModel(tdbDirectory);
             /*Incrementally read data to the Model, once per run , RAM > 6 GB*/

             FileManager.get().readModel( tdbModel, dataPath, "N-TRIPLES");

             tdbModel.close();

             return tdbDirectory;
        }

       void query(String tdbDirectory, String query1)
       {


    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(tdbDirectory);
              Model tdb = dataset.getDefaultModel();
              Query query = QueryFactory.create(query1);
              QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, tdb);
              /*Execute the Query*/
                ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
                System.out.println(results.getRowNumber());
                while (results.hasNext()) {
                      // Do something important
                    QuerySolution qs =   results.nextSolution();
              qs.toString();
                    System.out.println("sol "+qs);
                }
                   qexec.close();
               tdb.close() ;
       }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

            NewClass nc = new NewClass();
         String tdbd=    nc.read();
          nc.query(tdbd, "select ?code\n" +
    "WHERE\n" +
    "{\n" +
    "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Robert_H._Schuller> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> ?code.\n" +
    "}");


       }

}

}
```

**Result**

> *sol ( ?code = http://quotationsbook.com/author/6523 )*

Above query gives me code of the given author.

Please help me on this

Comment: Also, `sameAs` is not used for query comparison but to assert that two resources are the same. Was the former your intention here?

Comment: I reffered 2.1 section in http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#introduction  to write above query .To i have not used sameAs for query comparison purpose

Answer (score 6):

You cannot mix patterns and filters. You must first bind (ie select) the `?name` using a triple pattern and then filter the results. Jena basically complains because your SPARQL has invalid syntax.

Now, you could run the query below but your data only contains mapping between dbpedia URIs and quotationsbook URIs.

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>    
select ?code
where
{
   ?author <name> ?name .
   ?author owl:sameAs ?code .

   FILTER regex(?name, "^Rob")
}
```

The above means

1. Get names of authors
2. Get codes of authors
3. Include only authors whose name matches regex
4. Select their codes

Again this would only work for data available locally. Problem is that you do not have the actual names. Of course you could change you query to regex entire dbpedia identifiers, but that's not perfect.

```
FILTER regex(?author, "Rob")
```

What you can do, because dbpedia resources are [dereferencable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereferenceable_Uniform_Resource_Identifier), is wrap the name triple pattern in a [GRAPH pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#GraphPattern)

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select ?author ?code
where
{
   GRAPH  <file://path/to/dbpedia_quotationsbook.nt>
   {
      ?author owl:sameAs ?code .
   }

   GRAPH ?author
   {
      ?author <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?name .
      FILTER regex(?name, "^Rob")
   }
}
```

Here's what's happening

1. Get `?author`s and `?code`s from the import file (SPARQL GUI imports into a graph)
2. Treat `?author` as graph name, so that it can be downloaded from the web
3. Get `?author`'s `?name`s
4. Filter `?name`s which start with **Rob**

There are two important bits to make this work, depending on your SPARQL processor (I'm using [SPARQL GUI from dotNetRDF toolkit](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Tools/SparqlGui)).

Here's a screenshot of the results I got. Notice the highlighted settings and Fiddler log of dbpedia requests.

[image: federated query in SPARQL GUI]

Bottom line is I've just given you an example of [federated SPARQL query](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/).

Comment: I have checked above query by changing <name> and <code> with respective IRI , but there are no results i.e. QuerySolution.hasNext is false.

Comment: have you tried querying on dbpedia_quotationsbook.nt?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't dive into the actual data when I wrote the above. It seems that I made wrong assumptions. I'll update my question, though it turns out to be a tad more complex

Comment: Bugger, there seems to be some problem with my SPARQL GUI, because I'm not getting any matches from within the `GRAPH ?author` pattern. Please write how Jena works for you

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to help you further, sorry. I've never used Jena. You should explore executing federated queries with Jena and my examples above should help you.